# Defining 'condition' variable in DESeq2

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to use DESeq2.

When defining the condition variable, I am having trouble converting my input to a factor.

My input is a tibble from a spreadsheet I imported from excel.

```
condition<-Samples1[,9]
```

When I print this variable I get:

```
> condition
# A tibble: 88 x 1
   `Ever Use Tobacco (1=N, 2=Y)`
   <chr>                        
 1 N                            
 2 Y                            
 3 N                            
 4 N                            
 5 N                            
 6 N                            
 7 N                            
 8 N                            
 9 Y                            
10 N                            
# … with 78 more rows
```

When I check the type I get:

```
> str(condition)
tibble [88 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Ever Use Tobacco (1=N, 2=Y): chr [1:88] "N" "Y" "N" "N" ...
```

When I try to convert to factor, I get:

```
> factor<-factor(condition)
> factor
Ever Use Tobacco (1=N, 2=Y) 
                       <NA> 
Levels: c("N", "Y")
```

Another method I found for DESeq2 also does not work:

```
> conditionc<-factor(c(condition))
> conditionc
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Ever Use Tobacco (1=N, 2=Y) 
c("N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N") 
Levels: c("N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N")
>
```

The data should look like from [example](https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/f60c1934405c127f09a6):

```
> condition <- factor(c(rep("ctl", 4), rep("exp", 4)))
> condition
[1] ctl ctl ctl ctl exp exp exp exp
Levels: ctl exp
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `condition` is a `tibble/data.frame` with a single column.  We need to extract as a vector as the `x` in `factor` according to `?factor` is

> x - a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct values.

We can either extract the column with `[[`

```
factor(condition[[1]]) # // extract the first column
```

Or `unlist`

```
factor(unlist(condition))
```

Or extract with the column name

```
factor(condition$`Ever Use Tobacco (1=N, 2=Y)`)
```